# Yellow droplets from ceilling after water heater leak

Tags: water-heater, leak

I live in condominium, I got water pouring from upstairs in my store room. When I asked my upstairs neighbor he said that their water heater leaked.

For 20 minutes or so I saw clear water coming through from my ceilling , but after sometime I noticed yellow droplets on my ceilling, almost looked like oil droplets. Can anyone tell me why it got yellow color ? I am just concerned about some sort of chemical leak, I don't trust my neighbor.

I did some google search and found that water heater can have rusty water with leak, but I don't understand why most of the water was clear for almost 20 to 30 minutes , I saw yellow water only after sometime. Any explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Water leaking through the wall may at first be filtered to some extent. As the leak continues and or the wall materials are saturated materials may add to the water creating the yellow color, rust is usually red. The yellow can be from an array of building materials, wood products & insulation are common ones that would have a yellowing affect on top of the rust if not severe to be red.